# TT3 make img in 2nd column same height as content of 1st column

Tags: block-editor

I am still new to using TT3 theme and block editor. I want to create a two column element. In the first column will be paragraph text. In the second column can be either an image or a background image.

I want the height of the image/background image of the second column to always be the same height as the height of content in column 1.

For example, if I were to do this with HTML CSS only, I can use this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
                <style>
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: black;
}
.row {
}
.grid {
  width: 1440px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto / 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
.grid div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/SDnemCW.jpeg) center center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
                </style>
        </head>
        <body>
                <div class="grid">
                        <div>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                        </div>
                </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

And it would give an appearance like this:

[image]

You will observe that as I add more text in column 1, the image on the right will naturally grow in height to the same height as column 1.

How can I achieve this with just the native blocks in the TT3 theme?

---

NOTE:
I tried using a 2 column block and inserting an image on the right column. But the problem is that the second column will have a min-height of the image it contains.  And if column 1 has a height that is greater than the image, the image of column 2 does not automatically scale and crop to match the height of the content in column 1.  What's the idiomatic WordPress TT3 block way of achieving the same results as the the image described above?